# c# How to save flowlayoutpanel

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, flowlayoutpanel

I want to save buttons that I add in run to FlowLayoutPanel, but I dont know how and I didnt found it anywhere. Also I want to load them at start of program. So I want to save buttons name and text and then, at start of that program, load them. Im using c# & winforms.
So if someone could help me I would really appretiate it.

Comment: Try saving it into the string settings.

Comment: All controls you add to a control are in its Controls collection. Read: All Buttons are in the FlowLayoutPanel's Controls collection. You can loop through it and save their properties in any form and place you like. The more interesting question is: what do they do and how will restore that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in option or property to save controls information. You will have to do it manually.

1. Add option to save (in menu strip or a button)
2. In save method. Create a file and save all buttons information in it, in any format which is easy for you to parse.
3. On `Form Load` event, read that file and create the buttons a/c to the information you from the file.

For example you can save he information like:

> ControlType: Button; ControlText: NewButton1; Location: 240,240 Size:
>   50,20;
>
> ControlType: Button; ControlText: NewButton2; Location: 340,240 Size:
>   50,20;
>
> ControlType: Button; ControlText: NewButton3; Location: 440,240 Size:
>   50,20;

and whatever you want to define you can save into the file, and then read the file and parse the information.

You can parse it using `line.Split(';')`.

Comment: Hi, im sorry that im commenting so late but i thought that i will never understand it so i just gave up. But i found it again and i want to try it again. I dont understand it, can you make an example application? Or, even better, can you make it for [this application](https://mega.co.nz/#!IkRTwTJY!MkWrbVa0gv0JjPY6_4fCfXsHJwTeZ3H6YRxuyUGlz5A) ? I made the whole application, but i just dont know how to save that list of games. (you can take images from [here](https://mega.co.nz/#!V1oClTDD!nHJzCx9P5QOYQhFFiKGQbSteDx78p6eUH5bwAZ8arHI) ). Or just say me how to save it? Thanks a lot!